# How I can put a string contain data from an api into a HashMap or Dictionary?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm new to c# and I have created a library that contain currency exchange rate from an API to a string

```
using System.Net;
namespace RateLib
{
    public class CurrencyRate
    {
        public void getRate()
        {
            string url = "apikey";

            WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
            string txt = myClient.DownloadString(url);

        }
    }
}
```

Now, how I can put this `txt` string into a hashmap (if it does exist in c#) or a Dictionary ?

Comment: A map or dictionary doesn't care where the string came from - you can just put it in there like any other string. It's unclear what key you want, or what you've tried, or what went wrong though. For the second question - please stick to one question per post. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for a guide on asking good questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why do you need reflection to call the method?

Comment: @KlausGütter I am confident to say that OP wants to use reflection to construct an object from the json. If so, we dont have to use reflection for that. Let's see.

Comment: because I'm study reflection also, it not necessary but I still want to know how to, but I think I'll try to do it myself and probably will post another question if I see needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is to deserialize your json into a class containing a IDictionary for your rates. To do that we will use `System.Text.Json`'s [JsonSerializer.Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize__1_System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader__System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_).

Something like this:

```
public class Latest
{
    public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
    public string License { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, double> Rates { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var url = "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=69cb235f2fe74f03baeec270066587cf";
    var myClient = new WebClient();
    var json = myClient.DownloadString(url);
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions{PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase};
    var latest = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Latest>(json, options);
    Console.WriteLine(latest.Rates.First());
}
```

output

```
[AED, 3.6732]
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sOz32Y)

Last things, this apikey seems valid. You may want to change it now that it is exposed to the world.

Comment: What method of JsonSerializer I should use if I want to print all the values instead of first one ?

Comment: Replace the last line with `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", latest.Rates.Select(rate => $"{rate.Key},{rate.Value}")));`